# How to append values to an array in Bash by adding one element to the previous entry?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I have a list of numbers `1 2 3 4 5` that I am trying to organize into an array where the values are in a sequence where the current value is the summation of the previous values in the array (like this): `1 3 6 10 15`. My current code is as follows:

```
array=()
for n in `seq 1 5`
do
    if [ $n -eq 1 ]; then
        array+=($n)
    else
        value=$n
        index="$(($n-1))"
        array+=(`echo ${array[$index]}+$value`)
    fi

done
```

However, when I try checking the array `echo "${array[@]}"` I get `1 +2 +3 +4 +5`. How can I best go about solving this problem?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but your code boils down to: `for n in {1..5}; do ((array[n] = n * (n+1) / 2)); done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple if you know how to get the last element of the array in `bash` arrays!. You can just [use a negative index](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays) `${myarray[-1]}` to get the last element. You can do the same thing for the second-last, and so on; in Bash:

```
fbseries=()

for ((i=1; i<=5; i++)); do
    if [ "$i" -eq 1 ]; then
        fbseries+=("$i")
    else
        fbseries+=( $(( ${fbseries[-1]} + $i )) )
    fi
done
```

With the example and some modifications all you need is as above.

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close the a working code. Here I also added some improvements:

```
array=()
for n in {1..5}
do
    if [ "$n" -eq 1 ]; then
        array+=("$n")
    else
        value="$n"
        index="$((n-1))"
        array+=($((${array[$index]}+value)))
    fi
done
```

You can avoid using `seq`, and you don't need an `echo` but a calculus.

BTW, that's not a Fibonacci serie.