# Bash: Adding an element to a list where elements may or may not have spaces

Tags: bash

According to several threads in SO, I've developed the following mini-script:

```
list=(Alabama Alaska "New York")

list=$list" Oregon"

for state in  "${list[@]}"
do
    echo The next state is $state
done
```

The problem is that the output is

```
The next state is Alabama Oregon
The next state is Alaska
The next state is New York
```

instead of

```
The next state is Alabama 
The next state is Alaska
The next state is New York
The next state is Oregon
```

How would I append the element `Oregon`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316852/append-elements-to-an-array-in-bash https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935353/bash-incrementally-adding-to-an-array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52678358/how-to-append-values-to-an-array-in-bash-by-adding-one-element-to-the-previous-e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951506/add-a-new-element-to-an-array-without-specifying-the-index-in-bash

Comment: If you refer to an array variable as if it were a plain (non-array) variable, bash (mostly) treats that as referring to the first element of the array. So `list=$list" Oregon"` appends to the first element of the array, rather than adding a new element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list+=("Oregon")
```

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39935409/2840436